# ember-simple-auth custom authorizer is undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have my custom authorizer file that looks like this but is not working:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';
export default Base.extend({
    authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {

    var accessToken = this.get('session.content.secure.token');
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    }
}
});
```

After reviewing this post: http://simplabs.com/blog/2015/11/27/updating-to-ember-simple-auth-1.0.html it is still not clear to me,here should I call the authorizer? What about with the session store? Please can someone can clarify this to me, I'm getting the error authorizer is undefined:

My ajax call looks like this:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    gotQuote: false,
    quote: "",
    actions: {
        getQuote: function() {
                var that = this;
                this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:cusmtom', (headerName, headerValue) => { 
                const headers = {};
                headers[headerName] = headerValue;

                Ember.$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://www.example/api/quotes',
                    headers: headers,
                    success: function(response) {
                        that.setProperties({
                            quote: response.quoteText,
                            gotQuote: true
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Might be a typo (`'authorizer:cusmtom'` instead of `'authorizer:custom'`)?

Comment: i fixed that, but still getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined

Comment: I guess you're not injecting the session correctly somewhere. I also recognized you're using `jqXHR` and `requestOptions` in the authorizer. Please see the API docs for the actual authorizer API: http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthorizer.html#method_authorize

Comment: you were rigth it was the authorizer! thank you so much!